# Toolbar returns null with programmatically created Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I'm creating a ViewPager programmatically through code but on the resulting activity, I don't get an ToolBar. I have my toolbar set in both the xml file and in code but my code keeps saying that the toolbar is null.

The toolbar is being displayed in my main activity which contains my list fragment. The app crashes whenever I tap a list item which opens the fragment which is contained within the viewpager....or at least that's how I think it is. I'm at a complete loss and any help would great.

This is the stack trace:

```
03-24 00:33:50.128  26423-26423/com.fisheradelakin.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.fisheradelakin.criminalintent, PID: 26423
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fisheradelakin.criminalintent/com.fisheradelakin.criminalintent.CrimePagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:95)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:88)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:82)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:189)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivity.java:92)
        at com.fisheradelakin.criminalintent.CrimePagerActivity.onCreate(CrimePagerActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is CrimePagerActivity.java

```
public class CrimePagerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // create content view programmatically
        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
                return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mCrimes.size();
            }
        });

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
                if(crime.getTitle() != null) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(crime.getTitle());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        // set the current item of viewpager to the id of the crime selected rather than the first
        UUID crimeId = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
        for(int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++) {
            if(mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeId)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My xml for the fragment that is shown

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_details_label"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And last but not least, my CrimeFragment.java class:

```
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "com.fisheradelakin.android.criminalintent.crime_id";

    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UUID crimeId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

        mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mCrime.setTitle(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM F, yyyy", Locale.US);
        mDateButton.setText(sdf.format(mCrime.getDate()));
        mDateButton.setEnabled(false);

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
        mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // set the crime's solved property
                mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);

        CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

The ViewPager activity is called by my list fragment and I've included the code for that below

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "CrimeListFragment";

    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crimes_title);
        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();

        CrimeAdapter adapter = new CrimeAdapter(mCrimes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Crime c = ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

        // start crime pager activity
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimePagerActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID, c.getId());
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private class CrimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Crime> {

        public CrimeAdapter(ArrayList<Crime> crimes) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, crimes);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);
            }

            // configure the view for this crime
            Crime c = getItem(position);

            TextView titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);
            titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());

            TextView dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);
            dateTextView.setText(c.getDate().toString());

            CheckBox solvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox);
            solvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isSolved());

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `getActionBar()` instead of `getSupportActionBar()` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it still return null. I just realized i posted the wrong stack trace and I'm trying to get it updated. The problem is I'm trying to simply display the toolbar but it won't display because it says that the resource id is null

Comment: please share updated stack trace

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i edited the stack trace and put the correct one. And I changed to the code to how it is currently in front of me.

Comment: @fadelakin `setContentView(mViewPager);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));`. There is no toolbar in your layout. Its a view pager. hence its null

Comment: @Raghunandan i have the toolbar in a layout which i'm including in the fragment. the viewpager displays an instance of the fragment. assuming what you say is true, is there a way to add the toolbar to the viewpager even though i'm creating it programmatically?

Comment: @fadelakin: what value getting in `UUID crimeId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);` ? line. sure `CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);` line returning `null`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK the unique identifier id. it's the id that is attached to each list item. by matching the id to a list item, it's how i'm able to display the fragment and the specific item for the viewpager.

Comment: @fadelakin: then check you are getting right value or not in `crimeId` before passing it to `getCrime`

Comment: I believe this is due to not including the toolbar layout in your ActionBarActivity layout file like so: <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/> .

Comment: if you want to use the tool bar in each fragment then define the tool bar in your fragment layout and add like this  ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: In short inside your CrimePagerActivity you have not define the toolbar in layout. you did tried programmatically  to add the view pager what about tool bar. It is still null.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to set the toolbar in the fragment rather than in the viewpager activity like I was.